# Flot Charts and IE 11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, flot

We're developing an app using flot charts.  When we look at the same data rendered on Internet Explorer 11 vs, Firefox, we see different lines and different (stacked) bar charts.  That is, the data displayed by flot in IE looks plausible; it's just not correct.  It looks correct in Firefox.

Also, a line chart updated in real time (every 2 seconds) tends to "freeze" (get stuck on a single value) in IE, but not in FF.

Has anyone else experienced anything like this, or are we doing something wrong?

Comment: Can you provide some additional detail? Screenshots? Snippet of code used to render the chart?

Comment: If you open dev tools in emulation are you using Document Mode Edge?

Comment: I've tested the realtime example - http://www.flotcharts.org/flot/examples/realtime/index.html - which updates every 30ms against IE11, and see no issues.  Could you provide a jsFiddle or at least some code demonstrating the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Well I could find the answer to this question finally .

The issue here is When we use $http to get the data from the server in AngularJS a small issue arises only in Internet Explorer. The major problem of this issue is that if we want to refresh the data by sending the same call again to the server, Internet Explorer fetches the data from the cache and do not show the updated result. 
In case of Flot charts we make the same URL calls to receive the data for the subsequent time range so instead of fetching the new data it fetches the data from the cached URL so we can see that only one 1 request is made from UI to server to fetch the data as a result of which we just get a single data point for all time range .

Fix : POST method of the URL should be used instead of GET to prevent the caching .
$http.post(url) should be used instead of $http.get(url)